# AWS EC2 instance (free version) running low while training a simple ANN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a neural network with 100 epochs using Keras and the training works well till 64-65th epoch(better than my laptop - COREi3, 3GB RAM) after which it becomes very slow. I tried reconnecting, it again encounters the same issue at the same stage. I'm not sure what the problem is. Also any further suggestions for online servers to train neural networks (I'm learning). Cheaper the better (or free)

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

First, I should mention that there is no such thing as a "free version" of Amazon EC2. The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) provides a certain quantity of AWS services at no charge, but if the limits are exceeded, charges will apply.

The Free Tier includes:

> 750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro instance usage

This is enough time to run an instance for an entire month. Or, you could run two instances for half a month. Basically, the first 750 hours of above usage will not be charged.

Therefore, it sounds like you are using a `t2.micro` instance, which is a special type of instance.

From [CPU Credits and Baseline Performance for Burstable Performance Instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html):

> Burstable performance instances provide a baseline level of CPU performance with the ability to burst above that baseline level. The baseline performance and ability to burst are governed by CPU credits.

This means that the instance has the ability to **burst** to high levels of performance but it **cannot sustain that level of performance**. (Well, it can if the *T2 Unlimited* option is activated, but that will incur charges beyond the Free Tier.)

**Bottom line:** The Free Tier is intended as a means of exploring AWS services. It is not necessarily sufficient for Production workloads, nor Machine Learning.

The lowest-cost option for your situation would probably be [Spot Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances.html), which are up to 90% lower cost than On-Demand, but might be taken away with short notice.